# Regex for PHP. Search for words and return data after the words

Tags: php, regex, boost-regex

I'm trying to make a regex for a work I've been asked to but I'm having no luck making it efficient enough.
The objective is to make the following as efficient as it can be.
Objective number 1. Separate all text using the sentence endings (dot, 3 dots, exclamation point...).
Objective number 2 Get all the numbers that appear after the string 'em'
Here's an example of a possible small string and a regex for it. (the real one can be really hudge)
The regex:
old:
`(?:[^.!?:]|...)(?:(?:[^.!?:]|...)*?em (\d+))*`
new:
`(?:[.!?]|[.][.][.])(?:(?:[^.!?]|[.][.][.])*?\bem\b (\d+))*`

works for the string (I just made it up)
(I insert the . in the begining)

> .Foi visto que a batalha em 1939 foi. Claro que a data que digo ser em 1939 é uma farsa. Em 1938 já (insert em 1910) não havia reis.

What I wanted is to make a regex that does not backtrack as it simply does not need to backtrack. By making it like that I think I could save processing that this requires like... reducing from 30 seconds to 20s or even to 10s! Just for this1, it takes 1s to complete.
Add:
Thnx for the answers now I have one that does not fail. But still it does backtracks too much. Any solutions?
Add (to answer one deleted question):
Unfortunately I have no sample data, Who asked me to do this says he also does not have the sample data still this needs to be done "to yesterday". If you give me something that works with this text as efficient as it can be, I'm certain I can work with it and covert, if needed to something specific for this work. Else I'll ask here again.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is confusing, it sounds like you have two different tasks which is best acomplished with two different regexes. Here is a tested script that does what (I'm guessing) you want:

```php
<?php // test.php 20110430_1100
    // Test data.
    $text = 'Foi visto que a batalha em 1939 foi. Claro'.
        ' que a data que digo ser em 1939 é uma farsa. E'.
        'm 1938 já (insert em 1910) não havia reis.';

    // Part 1: Find all numbers after "em".
    $re1 = '/\bem\b\s*(\d+)\b/i';
    $count = preg_match_all($re1, $text, $matches);
    if ($count) $numbers = $matches[1]; // Array of number strings.
    else        $numbers = array();     // Else no numbers found.

    // Part 2: Split text into sentences.
    $re2 = '/(?<=[.!?])\s+/';
    $sentences = preg_split($re2, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    // Print out results.
    $ncnt = count($numbers); // Count of numbers found.
    printf("There were %d numbers following \"em\".\n", $ncnt);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $ncnt; ++$i) {
        printf("  Number[%d] = %s\n", $i + 1, $numbers[$i]);
    }
    $scnt = count($sentences); // Count of sentences found.
    printf("\nThere were %d sentences found.\n", $scnt);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $scnt; ++$i) {
        printf("  Sentence[%d] = \"%s\"\n", $i + 1, $sentences[$i]);
    }
?>
```

Here is the output from the script.

`There were 4 numbers following "em".`
`Number[1] = 1939`
`Number[2] = 1939`
`Number[3] = 1938`
`Number[4] = 1910`

`There were 3 sentences found.`
`Sentence[1] = "Foi visto que a batalha em 1939 foi."`
`Sentence[2] = "Claro que a data que digo ser em 1939 ├⌐ uma farsa."`
`Sentence[3] = "Em 1938 j├í (insert em 1910) n├úo havia reis."`

Comment: I'll use that, thx. (I shure hope that that's what they want, nothing that they have said is against that answer :))

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer about performance but:

- you shouldn't use '...' to match ... but '...' (otherwise, you match any sequence of 3 chars). Note that this might improve greatly your perf.
- I don't speak that language (spanish), but I think you want to match only the word "em", not the termination (e.g. balahem 1930 would match).
- you should not assume that you have only one space between 'em' and your number: Em__1950 (replace _ by space) would not match

**EDIT**:
About perf : matching anything (.) inside a repetition block forces the engine to go back and forth quite a while : If you can match explicit patterns, it will always be much quicker.

Comment: about: you should not assume that you have only one space between 'em' and your number: Em 1950 would not match. It's no problem. I'm using the case insensitive flag. Or is it faster if I use a class?

Comment: the pattern is simple. Find a single word em that has a number after it and the get that number, else ignore and go to the next one